# Order a matrix by column "patters" with R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

here is a data frame;

```
    204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213
X1  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
X2  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
X3  0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
X4  0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
X5  1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
```

and I would like to sort the columns in order to get the best representation in a heat map, where 1 are red and 0 white. 
So I should get something like :

```
    209 210 212 212 206 211 205 207 204 213
X1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
X2  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
X3  1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
X4  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
X5  1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
```

The idea is to gather the more 0 and 1 in the same line to get the best heat map representation possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort columns and rows as:

```
mat <- mat[, order(colSums(mat), decreasing = T)]
mat[order(rowSums(mat), decreasing = T),]

   209 210 206 211 212 205 204 207 208 213
X5   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
X1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
X2   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
X3   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
X4   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

## EDIT

Also you can consider a vector of weights:

```
weights <- c(5:1)

mat[, order(colSums(weights%*%mat), decreasing = T)]

   209 210 212 206 211 205 207 204 208 213
X1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
X2   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
X3   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
X4   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
X5   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1
```

Comment: In your output, 204 and 208 should be next to each other because they are both 1000 ... Maybe sort columns and rows in the same time would work?

Comment: I think you might just consider some weights and the work is done.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `df`, you could do:

```
df[, order(colSums(df), decreasing = TRUE)]
```